# Поиск одинакового слова в файле в СИ

Tags: c++, c

Смог написать код, который ищет одинаковые слова, но не так как хотелось бы. Нужно,чтобы он выводил примерно так: "the"= 2;(то есть нашел слово "the" 2 раза в тексте). И еще вопрос, можно ли как то проверять условие конца цикла не в ручную(сейчас у меня в тексте 3 строки, поэтому цикл меньше 3)
   Тут я записываю все слова из файле:

```
printf("\nТекст файла\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
        istr = fgets(str, LEN, fp);
        printf("%s", istr);
        for (char* istr = strtok(str, " .\t\n"); istr; istr = strtok(NULL, " .\t\n")) {
            strcpy(arr[k++], istr);
        }
    }

Тут ищу похожие слова в файле:

    printf("\nНахождение одинаковых слов\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < words; i++) { 
        for (int j = i + 1; j < words; j++) {
            if (strcmp(arr[i], arr[j]) == 0) {
                printf("%s==%s\n", arr[i], arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вот готовое решение: https://pastebin.com/vsQG1bPS

Answer (score 0):

Возможно где то допустил ошибки синтаксические... Давненько на с/с++ не программировал... (Реализация на с++) На работоспособность не проверял...

```
char ** array = new char*[10000];
size_t count[10000];
size_t length = 0;
const char * str = "Any text...";
array[length] = strtok(str, " ,.-!;\t");
while(array[length]){ // До тех пор пока указатель не равен \0 (Это конец строки) - будем искать слова и добавлять их в массив.
    array[++length] = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
}

size_t k = 0;
size_t counter = 0;
for(size_t i=0; i < length; ++i){
   for(size_t j=0; j < length; ++j){
      if(array[j] == array[i] && j != i){
         counter++;
      }
   }
   count[k++] = counter;
}
// Вывод:
for(size_t i=0; i < length; ++i){
   cout << array[i] + " = " + count[i] << endl;
}
delete array;
```

Comment: Это не Си++, это какой-то невообразимый микс из Си и вкраплений Си++. (На заметку -- это два уже практически разных языка)